# Apache Beam how many writes when using multiple tables

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using `Apache Beam` to read messages from PubSub and write them to BigQuery. What I'm trying to do is write to multiple tables according to the information in the input. To reduce the amount of writes, I am using windowing on the input from PubSub.

A small example:

```java
messages
    .apply(new PubsubMessageToTableRow(options))
    .get(TRANSFORM_OUT)
    .apply(ParDo.of(new CreateKVFromRow())
    .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(10L))))
    // group by key
    .apply(GroupByKey.create())
    // Are these two rows what I want?
    .apply(Values.create())
    .apply(Flatten.iterables())
    .apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
          .withoutValidation()
          .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
          .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
          .withExtendedErrorInfo()
          .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
          .to((SerializableFunction<ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow>, TableDestination>) input -> {
                                        // Simplified for readability
                                        Integer destination = (Integer) input.getValue().get("key");
                                        return new TableDestination(
                                                new TableReference()
                                                        .setProjectId(options.getProjectID())
                                                        .setDatasetId(options.getDatasetID())
                                                        .setTableId(destination + "_Table"),
                                                "Table Destination");
                                    }));
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but I was wondering how many writes are done to each window? If these are multiple tables, is it one write for each table for all elements in the window? Or is it once for each element, as each table might by different for each element?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using PubSub as a source your job seems to be a streaming job. Therefore, the default insertion method is `STREAMING_INSERTS`(see [docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.Method.html)). I don't see any benefit or reasons to reduce writes with this method as billig is based on the size of data. Btw, your example is more or less not really effectively reducing writes.

Although it is a streaming job, since a few versions the `FILE_LOADS` method is also supported. If `withMethod` is set to `FILE_LOADS` you can define `withTriggeringFrequency` on `BigQueryIO`. This setting defines the frequency in which the load job happens. Here the connector handles all for you and you don't need to group by key or window data. A load job will be started for each table.

Since it seems it is totally fine for you if it takes some time until your data is in BigQuery, I'd suggest to use `FILE_LOADS` as loading is free opposed to streaming inserts. Just mind the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) when defining the triggering frequency.